# mongoose not connecting to localhost

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I seem to have issues when trying to create a mongoose connection. I am following a book published in 2014 so my immediate response was to check the mongoose docs but they agree that the book gives the correct format. Below is my connection:

```
var dbURI = 'mongodb://localhost/Loc8r';
mongoose.connect(dbURI);
```

As soon as I add these lines, I get the following error:

```
Mongoose connection error: mongodb://127.0.0.1/Loc8r
(node:743) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
(node:743) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

If I remove the connection, I have no errors...but that would defeat the purpose of trying to connect to a DB. I also tried substituting `localhost` in the URI for `127.0.0.1` which is known to solve some issues but I had no luck there either. I am running the `localhost` on a simple `$nodemon` command via terminal and nothing else.

Useful info:

- MongoDB v3.6.3
- Mongoose v5.0.10
- Express v4.15.5
- Node v8.9.4

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please check whether you're able to connect to the mongo via shell?

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
  , assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';

// Use connect method to connect to the server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");

  db.close();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going on the right path but you forgot to put the port on which MongoDB runs,
MongoDB runs on the port `27017`

Do not forget to start MongoDB server, If you are on `mac` open terminal and enter `mongod` and it will start your MongoDB server then run your code it will work fine.

```
var dbURI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/Loc8r';
mongoose.connect(dbURI);
mongoose.connection.on("connected", () => {
    console.log("Connected to database");
});
mongoose.connection.on("error", (err) => {
  console.log("Database error:" + err);
});
```

Comment: This still throws the same error, I'm afraid. And when I ran mongod it mentioned:

Data directory /data/db not found., terminating

and shut down with code 100. Also happened when I tried to sudo the command.

Comment: It shows you did not configure MongoDB variable paths and all

Answer (score 0):

I apologise for this as I was able to find the solution myself but I guess this may help others some day.

The fault lay with the fact that I only installed MongoDB via Homebrew and I stopped as soon as MongoDB was literally "installed" and considered MongoDB to be "installed". I went back to look at how MongoDB should properly be installed and I noticed that I did not make the directory `/data/db` and give it its permissions which was an important step.

Once I did this, I ran `mongod` globally, and `nodemon` on a separate terminal, locally at the root of the app and it worked completely fine and got a successful message in the console. Every time I tried to connect, it was searching for `/data/db` which it obviously could not find as I had not made it. But I would not have came to this conclusion if Nikhil had not mentioned running `mongod`.

To summarise, ensure you follow all installing steps in future.